# Querystring data gets truncated

Tags: jquery

When I check "view source > frame info" on the window produced by the jQuery code below, it cuts off the querystring at the &type=image. I'm url encoding the ampersands properly, right?

```
Address: ...wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=28&type=image&

function wpe_customImages($initcontext)
{
global $post;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var fileInput = '';
jQuery('#wpe-uploadAttachments').click(function() {
    fileInput = jQuery(this).prev('input');
    formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
    post_id = jQuery('#post_ID').val();
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id='+post_id+'&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;wpe_idCustomAttachment=true');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have asked wether or not you have done the url encoding for the ampersands right, then my answer is: No.

You are calling a javascript function, you're not outputting something as x(ht)ml. You therefore do not need to encode `&` as `&amp;`. The function is expecting a URL not a string that contains an xml encoded url.

But that's probably nit-picking.

The reason why this does not work is, that tb_show() cut's away anything after the first `TB_` it finds in that URL, and only the part of the URL before that string is preserved for the iframe src. So you need to move the `TB_iframe=true` to the end of the parameter. This should do the trick:

```
tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id='+post_id+'&amp;type=image&amp;wpe_idCustomAttachment=true&amp;TB_iframe=true');
```

BTW, wordpress is open source. You can just look to find the tb_show() function in source and look why something is happening or not. This can help to find out specific stuff. I didn't do anything else :)

Comment: That's a very good point, it's not really an immediately obvious problem but i do specifically remember noticing that issue myself (the TB_ parameter positioning). Good call hakre.. :)